# Using a case statement in conjunction with stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Part of my query looks like this:

```
  contNumber = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(t.contNumber))
                FROM dbContactNumbers t
                where d.contid = t.contid
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''),
```

I had to use this because I have a one-to-many relationship and this is a quick and easy way to return the relevant values on one line.

I would like to do a case statement based on this field to NULL anything that equals `44` but I get syntax errors when trying to use a normal case statement anywhere in my query, like this:

```
case contnumber when '44' then NULL else contnumber,

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
```

What's the correct syntax to do this case statement, assuming this it's even possible? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Seems like you are missing 'END' at the end of the case statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
contNumber = CASE WHEN STUFF((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(t.contNumber))
                FROM dbContactNumbers t
                where d.contid = t.contid
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') = ' 44' THEN NULL
             ELSE STUFF((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(t.contNumber))
                FROM dbContactNumbers t
                where d.contid = t.contid
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
             END
```

Another way is to wrap it with subquery/CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT   contNumber = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(t.contNumber))
                FROM dbContactNumbers t
                where d.contid = t.contid
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''),
-- ...
)
SELECT case contnumber when ' 44' then NULL else contnumber, ...
FROM cte
```

---

And the clearest solution is to use [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql):

```
contNumber = NULLIF(STUFF((SELECT ', ' + RTRIM(LTRIM(t.contNumber))
                FROM dbContactNumbers t
                where d.contid = t.contid
                FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''), ' 44')
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this will ever work. The stuff adds comma+space as separator and at start. You are trimming off the first character. That means the result will start with a space

Comment: wouldn't it be more logical to trim off another character ? stuff(var, 1,2,'')

Comment: I noticed the leading space, which is why the r/ltrims are there. It didn't work but I've just removed it in my related C# application instead

Answer (score 1):

The answer by lad2025 is great (especially about `NULLIF` (+1 from my side), just a hint:

You cannot use a *computed* column like you'd use a *named variable*. Yes you can repeat the expression, but this is very hard to read in more complex cases.

But there is `CROSS APPLY`.

This allows you to create a **row-based derived table**. With a construction like the following you can shift the computation (even many columns) into a derived set of columns, which you can use like a named variable.

The following example is senseless, but shows the principles:

```
SELECT object_id 
      ,[name]
      ,namedVariable
FROM sys.objects
CROSS APPLY(SELECT 'Anything') AS A(namedVariable)
```